# PayPal Marketplace integration with react-native

Tags: react-native, paypal

I can't find the best way to integrate PayPal with my Nodejs (Nestjs) React-native app

This App is a marketplace, for PayPal Multiparty we need to onboard the seller (Done), next we need to create an order => authorize the order => capture the order, and here I have problems, when I create an order and I redirect the user to the correct redirect URL, and this is what we get [image: paypal create order]

When the user clicks on Continue to Review Order the page refreshes (it's a webview component) without any redirect to the payment. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a return_url and cancel_url when creating the order? This "refresh" behavior happens when not specifying a location to return to.

For native, it should be a deeplink back to your app, and you can then proceed to show a review page, with an action that will capture the order.

---

If you want to skip showing a review page and proceed immediately with a capture and showing the result (success/failure message), you need to change the verbiage of the last button at PayPal, Continue to Review Order -> Pay Now. Do this by setting `payment_source.paypal.experience_context.user_action` (or deprecated `application_context.user_action`) to `PAY_NOW` at order creation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this solved my problem but I passed to handled html with paypal javascript sdk